# Form Authentication woes, calling http handler on app2 from app1 not authenticating

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, httphandler

I have 2 asp.net web applications.

```
http://app1.local/
```

and

```
http://app2.local/
```

App2 has a httpHandler that takes in some credentials, and logs the user in using forms authentication.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(cookieUserName, createPersistentCookie);
HttpCookie authCookie = context.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

I run this directly in my browser and when I open up another page on app2, I am logged in just fine.

**The problem:**

On app1 I have a login page, that does a httpwebrequest to the httpHandler on app2.  For some reason, **when I login with the same credentials and then go to app2 I am not logged into the app2 website**.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Do they have the same cookie name? (FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName) If they do they might be overwritting each other.

The fact that the credentials are the same is irrelevant (I think).  Because they are two different apps/sites they don't have an explicit trust relationship between them - users need to authenticate themselves directly (not surprising).  So if the same Forms Authentication cookie is being overwritten your previous authentication is lost.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that App2 is your Authenticator Service which is used by other Apps(here just App1) for authentication of the user.

Now to login directly via App2 login page and to authenticate user in App1 via http request call is entirely different even though Authentication only happens in App2.

**How to debug and resolve:**

Http request call made via App1 to App2 would mostly be calling different method than direct login in App2. This http request from App1 to App2 doesn't involve any browser interaction - it's internal call between these 2 apps. One way to solve it would be that App1 should also set same cookies as App2. 
Other clues can be found out if you can figure out the differences in both the methods and bridge the gap.